# Can't access instances in openstack

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I just installed openstack on CentOS 7 with VMware workstation.
My problem is that I could not access my VM from outside, I'm assigned floating IP to my VM and security group is fine.

Comment: There are not very much information and I have no experience with vmware, but maybe it helps you anyway and its only a suggestion: I had also one time the same problem, that I couldn't connect my VMs and the solution in my case was, to change the public accessible provider network in the openstack deployment, where the floating-ips belongs to, from a network of type `vlan` into a network of type `flat`.

Comment: Where can i edit network type

Comment: The type can not be set afterwards in each case. It would be necessary to delete the old network with `openstack network delete` and create it again with the new type (see also https://docs.openstack.org/newton/install-guide-ubuntu/launch-instance-networks-provider.html#create-the-provider-network). But based on the low amount of information in your question, I don't know, if this solves your problem, so be aware of this, before you delete your old network.

Comment: What info do you need to guide me

Comment: You could add information about the network-configuration in your openstack-deployment and how you connected your vm, or add a link to the manual you used to create your openstack-setup, or try to collect some hints, which could be helpful. For example: when you ping your VM, can you see ARP-requests and reply in tcpdump in the openstack-network, or can you access the VM over VNC to check if the system within your VM booted successfully. Maybe with information like this, someone can help you.

Comment: Would you please connect my pc via anydesk or some thing else

Comment: When i ping VMs it says dst host unreachable and even in host i can't ping mn v

Comment: ... Ping my VMs and aslo ip addr of router that connect to external network, type flat